# Vue / Laravel - Formdata.append displaying null value on edit

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a working `post` method for storing a photo + the first name of the user.

```
 // front-end
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('photo', this.tableItem.photo);
 formData.append('first_name', this.tableItem.first_name);
 await axios.post('/api/employees', formData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }})

 // back-end
 $employee = Employee::create([
  'first_name' => $request->first_name,
 ]);
```

Now if I edit the `first_name`, the `put` method is a success but the value is displayed as blank

```
  Object.assign(this.tableData[this.editedIndex], this.tableItem)
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('photo', this.tableItem.photo);
  formData.append('first_name', this.tableItem.first_name);
  await axios.put('/api/employees/' + this.tableItem.id, formData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }})

  $employee->update([
    'first_name' => $request->first_name,
  ]);
```

If I removed the `formData` and replaced it with `this.tableItem` everything is working as intended. Even if a I put an `await` for `Object.assign`, the new value input is still not captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [known bug on PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55815), [Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9226) and Laravel as well, a workaround is to append `_method` param with `PATCH` or `PUT` value to your `formdata` and use `axios.post` instead:

```php
formData.append('_method', 'PUT');
await axios.post(
    '/api/employees/' + this.tableItem.id,
    formData,
    //{...
```

Check this issue on Laravel repo for more info: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457#issuecomment-340156084

Comment: So this has been a bug since way back. Thank you very much!